Is there an efficient (and also free or cheap) way to turn a video file into a time based composite image?
I'm doing a physics project with my math class.
My students recorded a videos of balls being dropped.  (We are studying acceleration and how to model motion with quadratic equations.)
The goal is to turn this video into a composite image where the path of the ball is shown by taking every few frames and overlaying this image.
I'm going to try to use Mathematica (this is something I'm already familiar with) but I wondered if there was something out there that was already put together.

Are you on a mac or PC? Do you have access to Photoshop or any Adobe software?

Here's how you'd do it in Photoshop. I'm sure you could do something similar using GIMP which is free software.
Example using this video, saved as an mp4 using yt-dlp (or you could use an online video converter):

From the File menu, choose 'Import Video Frames to Layers'
Select the range of frames you want to import
Select all the layers
Make them all visible (clicking on the eye icons):

Set the layer mode to lighten:


Result:

